# Compare values of generic types

Tags: c#, generics

I've got this function which should compare two states. Type State is a generic one. So my solution was making a delegate:

```
Func<State, State, bool> identityFun
```

which I'm passing as argument in function where comparison should be made:

```
 if(!node.checkIf(s, identityFun))
```

Problem I'm trying to solve is 8-Puzzle so in this case State is `int[,]`. In Main function I definded function identical:

```
 private static bool identical(int[,] arg1, int[,] arg2) {
        for(int i=0; i<arg1.GetLength(0); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<arg1.GetLength(1); j++) {
                if (arg1[i, j] != arg2[i, j])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: "Unfortunately this doesn't work. " What does that mean? Any error? Exception? Unexpected results? Anyway I can´t see how your Func relates to the `identical`-method at all. Can you provide the code where you call that method?

Comment: "this doesn't work" is not very descriptive.

Comment: Your `identical` implementation is not correct by the way. Suppose `arg1` is 1x1 array with single element 0. `arg2` is 1000x1000 array with (0,0) element also 0. Your function will treat them as identical.

Comment: "Type State is a generic one" Than you have to provide the type-arguments to `State`-type: `State<MyType>`.

Comment: Okay, so basically I want to add node with state to queue only when particular state didn't appear before. So I have to check if it already exists on path to root. I'm doing this with function checkIf. I have class Searching with methid TreeSearch which returns State. So I call it in Main like that: Searching.TreeSearch(p, s, identical). There is no error, exception, nothing like that. Program is making too many comparisons by taking states which were compared before.

Comment: I have two arrays with the same size 3x3. They must have the same size.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. It was in function going through parents of nodes. English isn't my native language so sorry. Anyway thanks for help everyone.